# Virtualmin change apache port

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, nginx

I'm trying to change apache port to 82 (to confugure nginx):
I changed:

- NameVirtualHost 94.198.110.11:80 to NameVirtualHost 94.198.110.11:82 in apache2.conf
- Listen 94.198.110.11:80 to Listen 94.198.110.11:82 in ports.conf
- VirtualHost 94.198.110.11:80 to VirtualHost 94.198.110.11:82 in sites-available/default

And changed manually ports in every virtualhost. But when I create new host, it creates with 80 default port, and in the prev. config file are added lines with port 80.
How can I change the default port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default port for newly created virtual hosts via:

System Settings -> Server Templates -> Default Settings -> Apache website -> Port number for virtual hosts.

(Taken from Virtualmin support request at http://www.virtualmin.com/node/17543 (requires registration))

Comment: Oh, of course, I missed this parameter. Thank you!